# Monitor.PulaseAll throws error

Tags: c#

What is wrong with this example, it throws error "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code" at Monitor.PulaseAll(yyy) ?

```
class Program
{
    static object yyy = 1;

    public static void test(int x)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            lock (yyy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("T" + x.ToString());
                while (x != (int)yyy)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(yyy);
                    continue;
                }

                Console.Write(new string(x.ToString()[0], 20));

                yyy = 1 + (int)yyy;
                yyy = ((int)yyy == 4) ? 1 : yyy;

                Console.WriteLine("------------------------1--");
                Monitor.PulseAll(yyy);
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------2--");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main ()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { test(3);}));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { test(2);}));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { test(1);}));

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t3.Start();

        while (true)
            Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The error here is ***changing the lock object***.

To Pulse[All] you must have the lock. It *looks* like you have a lock, but if you look carefully you reassign `yyy` in the code, so that is a *different object*.

For this reason, lock objects are commonly `readonly` fields.

Also, locking on a boxed value-type or a string is generally a bad idea; the most appropriate lock object is:

```
private readonly object syncLock = new object();
```

(can additionally be `static` if needed)

Being a private instance avoids unexpected lock conflicts; beig readonly avoids accidental reassignment.